# Erro ao rodar Script ruby com server Appium externo

Tags: ruby

Estou tentando rodar um script bem básico em ruby. A idéia é simplesmente validar que meu script appium executa utilizando um server de appium externo.

A conexão com o celular remoto é feita normalmente e o Appium abre o aplicativo, mas logo após isso o recebo uma mensagem de erro e o script é encerrado.

informações relevantes
Appium 1.20.2
Ruby 2.6.3

erro:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
    10: from test.rb:26:in `<main>'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/appium_lib-10.6.0/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:561:in `start_driver'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/appium_lib-10.6.0/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:382:in `appium_server_version'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/appium_lib_core-3.11.1/lib/appium_lib_core/driver.rb:459:in `appium_server_version'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/has_remote_status.rb:25:in `remote_status'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:55:in `status'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:567:in `execute'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:167:in `execute'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/appium_lib_core-3.11.1/lib/appium_lib_core/common/base/http_default.rb:98:in `call'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:114:in `request'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:98:in `create_response': unexpected response, code=404, content-type="text/html" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /api/mobile/wd/hub/status</pre>
</body>
</html>
    3: from test.rb:26:in `<main>'
    2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/appium_lib-10.6.0/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:561:in `start_driver'
    1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/appium_lib-10.6.0/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:381:in `appium_server_version'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/appium_lib-10.6.0/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:384:in `rescue in appium_server_version': Appium::Core::Error::ServerError (Appium::Core::Error::ServerError)```
````

Comment: Não parece ser um erro com o seu script, mas que o servidor que o script tentou acessar estava fora do ar, ou então retornou 404.